# jQuery: How to slide down an absolute div along with another div that is sliding down?

Tags: jquery

I have a text container that is absolutely positioned on the bottom of the page and above it, there is a Show/Hide button (which is also absolutely positioned).

I need to slide the Show/Hide button up and down along with the text container when it slide toggles. When the text container slides down, the button must follow it and remain visible at the bottom of the page. When the text container slides up, the button must slide up with it. I can't seem to get this to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button">
     <span>Hide</span><span style="display:none;">Show</span></div>
  <div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
  $(this).find("span").toggle();
  $(".container").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UDe8r/1/

Comment: does the `.container` has to be `position:absolute`? From jquery docs: `position:absolute` can sometimes cause problems. change it to `position:relative`.

Comment: Yes it'd be good if this can be made to work without changing the `position`s. The demo I've shown above is part of a large code, which is working perfectly otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/fpPJz/3/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper a').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).text() == 'Show')
            $(this).text('Hide');
        else
            $(this).text('Show');         
        $('.wrapper .content').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

## CSS

```
.wrapper {
    height: 400px;    
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper #button{
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    padding:0;
}
.wrapper #button a{
    padding:0 5px;
    text-align:right;
    background:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.container{    
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
.content{
    display:none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I noticed you changed `.wrapper` position to `absolute`. In fact I need to keep the `.wrapper` position to `relative` (see my original demo). Is it possible to make this work based on my original CSS?

Comment: Check update demo here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/fpPJz/3/... This didn't your css position, but you need to move your button inside container and some background color changes.