# On button click show information sliding up and pushing the button upwards using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a foreach loop which displays a list of items using relative and absolute positioning, and on the bottom I would like to add a button (which is at the bottom of the container), which when pressed, shows/hides the given information, pushing the button with itself. I've looked at a couple of stackoverflow questions which had basically the same problem, but I couldn't find a solution which would work in my case.

Here are the codes for the problem (since I've tried a couple solutions, the style positions might not be logical, if you see anything weird please let me know):

The view:

```
<ul class="events>
@foreach (var events in Model)
{
//absolute positioned div-s
  <li>
    <div class="eventActions">
            <button class="toggleBet">Place bet</button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Event details", "Details", "Event", new { eventId = events.Id }, null)
            <div class="betContent">@Html.Partial("_BetPartial", new BetViewModel(events))</div>

        </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The styles:

```
.events > li .eventActions {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 200px;

}

.events > li .toggleBet {
    display: inline-block;

}

.events > li .betContent {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1s;
}

.events > li .eventActions.open .betContent {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

The jQuery:

```
$(".toggleBet").on("click",function(e) {
    $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("open");
});
```

Here is a fiddle which shows what I would like to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/fpPJz/3/ (credits to user yeyene, from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267307/jquery-how-to-slide-down-an-absolute-div-along-with-another-div-that-is-sliding))

And here is the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmcFu.png) of my project so far (I would like to extend the list items height, move the links lower and make them move up when clicked)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What specific problem are you having ? Your code should do the visibility toggle.

Comment: It does that yes, but the content is opening downwards and going over everything and I would like it to open upwards and push the button with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest forgetting about the .slideToggle method and just using a CSS class on the parent container, then use the `max-height` property to toggle between open and closed (or just `height` if you already know exactly how big the container should be when opened).

Here's a simple fiddle showing how you can do this with "pure" CSS by just adding a class to a container: https://jsfiddle.net/8ea3drce/

---

For good measure, below is the code used in the above JS fiddle:

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="trigger">Trigger</a>
  <ol class="content">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .trigger {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1em;
}

.container .content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 0; // This suppresses the element's height.
  overflow: hidden; // This keeps internal elements from being visible when height is suppressed.
  transition: max-height .5s; // This animates the motion when max-height is released. This isn't usually perfect. The closer max-height comes to be with the actual height of the element, the better. Fixed heights might be ideal.
}

.container.open .content {
  max-height: 300px; // This releases the element's height to be as large as it would naturally be, up to 500px.
}
```

#### Javascript/jQuery

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this.parentNode).toggleClass('open');
})
```

Comment: I did everything according to your code and it still opens the content downwards. I think I tried almost every combination of absolute and relative
 positions but every time it opened it downwards. Any idea why?

Comment: I assume the container you want to open is the .events element? If so, that needs to be absolute positioned, not relative. Its parent container will have to be relative, fixed, or absolute in order for the change to have an effect. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: No, in the case of my posted code, betContent is the one that would contain a partial view and I would like to put that into that div instead of "content". Does that change anything?

Comment: Can you add your current styles for .betContent? I don't see what you're currently doing with that node in terms of CSS.

Comment: Okay, analyzing your code (without full context) and based on your statement that "every time it opened it downwards," I now believe that your CSS rule on `.events > li .eventActions` is opening downward because it's absolute positioned and oriented from the top. What happens if you replace the `top: 355px;` property with `bottom: 0;`?

Comment: I just tried it and it still does the same, here's an image on how chrome sees the object, hope it might help you someway. https://i.imgur.com/mnE5get.png

Comment: That's a start. How does chrome see its child element, .toggleBet?

Comment: Okay, so the element is currently sliding up from the bottom when you click on it? Or is .toggleBet in that position by default or does it move to that position after opening? Would be easier to tell if your screenshots included the style rules and bounding boxes for all of the elements involved.

Comment: Here is the <li> : https://i.imgur.com/rVaTI7c.png
and here is the .betContent in closed and open state, it's still sliding down from the bottom of the button, while the button stays in place.
closed: https://i.imgur.com/sSplrsa.png
open: https://i.imgur.com/4vr4aK4.png

Comment: Got it. So far so good. And what about the `.eventActions` element? Did you replace the `top: 355px` property with `bottom: 0`?

Comment: Oh, you added `height: 200px` to `.eventActions`. Does it work without that? What is that there for?

Comment: Woah, I don't know how that came about, I deleted it and now it's working. Thank you so much for all this!

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea of classtoggling as shown in Dom's answer, setting the absolute position's anchors correctly and deleting the interfering height attribute solved the problem!